# facebook-credits-api. sample code Error_code : 1383004

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-credits

I downloaded the sample from github here (https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample)

End testing. but error occured.

`*Error message returned from Facebook:
1383004
Order::update_order called with invalid state transition:3 -> 0*`

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I need to change Migration "signed_request for Canvas", confirm at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ Advanced tab.

Sample code have error.

function parse_signed_request's part

```
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
   error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
   return null;
}
```

Error occurs there. I think that code not important that code is just for check. So I set the code commented.

And it worked!!

Comment: Which Stetting You told i didn't found i have same problem please help